# Golang VSCode how can I stop/pause auto importing?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm finding the auto import active in Visual Studio Code for Golang is adding the incorrect package references automatically. Noticing that this has happened then going and correcting it all the time is a real pain.

To avoid this, and other annoying interfering handholding, is it possible to turn off auto importing or at least pause it for a while? Well keeping other nice features. I know I can just use a very simple text editor instead. *(Basically tell the pushy pair programming partner to go and fetch a couple of coffees.)*

Comment: FWIW, I've been programming for more than four decades and use still use ViM (with extensions such as Gopls) rather than an IDE like VSCode. Still, I find it hard to believe that VSCode gets something so fundamental wrong so often that you feel the need to disable the behavior. I've read a lot of SO questions involving VSCode and can't recall anything like what you are reporting. So either I have an inappropriately high opinion of VSCode (despite having never used it) and it does suck as bad as you imply or there is something unusual about how you are using that IDE.

Comment: @KurtisRader, VS Code is for the most part is an excellent IDE, and to be fair most of the problems tend to be with how particular third party extensions are written, in this case the Golang one. Golang itself and quite a few of its third party tools, are somewhat infuriating; often providing limited or obtuse documentation for complex things, well on the the other hand imposing overt heavy handed control when it isn't wanted. It just really struggles to get the right balance.

Comment: @KurtisRader 40 years experience and you still program like it's 1983. Things have moved on. I can't imagine doing a project of any size in vim :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can disable auto imports in Visual Studio Code for the Go extension:

1. Open the settings in Visual Studio Code by clicking on the gear icon in the bottom left corner or by pressing Ctrl + , (comma).
2. In the search bar at the top of the settings window, type "go" to filter the settings related to the Go extension.
3. Look for the setting called "Go: Add Tags" and uncheck the checkbox. This setting controls whether the Go extension should automatically add import statements when you use a new identifier in your code.
4. Close the settings window.

After disabling the "Go: Add Tags" setting, the Go extension should no longer automatically add import statements when you use new identifiers in your code. However, keep in mind that you won't get auto-import suggestions anymore, so you'll need to manually import the packages you need.

> NOTE: Do check the documentation and go version.

Comment: The interface appears to have changed. I don't get a checkbox but instead 5 settings with little explanation

Comment: same, this is not valid anymore. How do I prevent auto import.